# Angularjs/ASP.NET: How can I read a json returned from my controller and set it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 5 and have a function in my controller that returns a Json object. I'm also using angular for my javascript, and I'm trying to declare a variable equal to the text that's returned from reading the Json file. I'm new to coding, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling the method in your mvc controller ? Where do you want to set the value ? in your angular controller scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i do it in mvc is that I have my js service like that :

```
angular.module('Something')
.controller('SomethingController', ['$scope', 'SomethingService', 'Notification', 'Enum', ....
```

than call your cs controller from the service:

```
        somethingService.getSomthing().then(function (data) {
            $scope.value = data.Somthing;
        });
```

the service:

```
angular.module('Something')
.factory('SomethingService', ['$http', 'Notification', function ($http, Notification) {
return {    getSomething: function () {
            var promise = $http.post('../../Area/Something/GetSomething')
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function (error) {
                    Notification.error("We encountered an error while retrieving Something", error);
                });
            return promise;
        }
    };
}
]);
```

the service will call the cs controller

Comment: Thanks, this solution works